How to validate n array of fields with Vee-validate?
I have simple form like this :
app.vue
  dynamic form
  <div v-for="(item, i) in formData" :key="i">
    <input placeholder="name" v-model="item.name" />
    <span v-if="nameError">{{ nameError }}</span>

    <input placeholder="age" v-model="item.age" />
    <span v-if="ageError">{{ ageError }}</span>
  </div>

  <button @click="data.push({ name: '', age: '' })">Add New Row</button>
  <button @click="onSubmit">submit</button>
  {{errors}}

when you click on add a new row will be created .
app.vue script
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useField, useForm } from 'vee-validate';

const formData = ref([{ name: '', age: 0 }]);
const { errors } = useForm(); // Use `useForm` for validation context
const { value: nameField, errorMessage: nameError } = useField('name'); 

// Define fields using useField
const { value: ageField, errorMessage: ageError } = useField('age');
async function onSubmit() {
  const isValid = await Promise.all([
    nameField.validate(),
    ageField.validate(),
  ]);

  if (isValid.every(Boolean)) {
    // Validation successful, handle form submission
    console.log('Form is valid, submit:', formData.value);
    nameField.reset();
    ageField.reset(); // Clear fields on successful validation
  } else {
    // Display error messages
  }

now I wanna validate this with vee-validate ,
how can I do it ?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ryf5wz?embed=1&file=src%2FApp.vue
